# How can I create a 3D representation of an object with known coordinates and adjacency table in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, programming, data

Basically I want to create an object with specified coordinates and adjacency table, like in page two of [this article](http://media.pearsoncmg.com/aw/aw_lay_linearalg_updated_cw_3/cs_apps/lay03_02_cs.pdf).

I'm completely new to using *Mathematica*, any help would be great!

EDIT: So I want to plot an object like this, [image]

and then I want to apply a perspective projection to it. (I will make the coordinates of the object I wish to plot, and will make an adjacency matrix which notes which points are connected and which are not). How could I do this in *Mathematica*?

Here are examples for the coordinate list and adjacency matrix (kindly supplied by kguler):

```
pnts = {{-6.5, -2, -2.5}, {-6.5, -2, 2.5}, {-6.5, .5, 2.5}, {-6.5, .5, -2.5}, 
        {-2.5, .5, -2.5}, {-2.5, .5, 2.5}, {-.75, 2, -2.5}, {-.75, 2, 2.5},
        {3.25, 2, -2.5}, {3.25, 2, 2.5}, {4.5, .5, -2.5}, {4.5, .5, 2.5}, 
        {6.5, .5, -2.5}, {6.5, .5, 2.5}, {6.5, -2, 2.5}, {6.5, -2, -2.5}};

adjmat = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
         {1, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
         {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
         {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}};
```

Comment: You should look through [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphicsAndSoundOverview.html) and learn the basics. Then try to implement what you want and come back with a specific question when you get stuck. In particular, you need to post an example.

Comment: So we can get a better idea of what you are looking for, can you give us an example of such an object? Edit your quest to add the description; do not put it into a comment.

Comment: I thinks it's clear enough what OP wants. He has a list of coordinates of vertices of a polyhedron and he has an adjacency matrix, which describes where edges of said polyhedron exist (between which pairs of vertices exists an edge). Studying documentation of [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) will surely help.

Comment: I concur with @LLlAMnYP that the question is clear enough. It's only lacking some example data to work with. As he shows making some yourself is not that difficult either. I wouldn't cllose it for this reason.

Comment: At the time of the mods' comments OP had not yet been edited.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The question looks OK now. When I saw it, all it had was a link to an external PDF. That's never OK for an acceptable question.

Comment: @jens Fair enough, didn't see that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
adjmat = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
          {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
          {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
          {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
          {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}};

pnts = {{-6.5, -2, -2.5}, {-6.5, -2, 2.5}, {-6.5, .5, 2.5}, {-6.5, .5, -2.5}, 
        {-2.5, .5, -2.5}, {-2.5, .5, 2.5}, {-.75, 2, -2.5}, {-.75, 2, 2.5},
        {3.25, 2, -2.5}, {3.25, 2, 2.5}, {4.5, .5, -2.5}, {4.5, .5, 2.5}, 
        {6.5, .5, -2.5}, {6.5, .5, 2.5}, {6.5, -2, 2.5}, {6.5, -2, -2.5}};
```

**Using  `AdjacencyGraph`:**

```
grph = AdjacencyGraph[adjmat, VertexCoordinates -> pnts, 
  VertexSize -> .01, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
grph2 = AdjacencyGraph[adjmat, VertexCoordinates -> pnts, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", EdgeStyle -> Thick, VertexSize -> 0, 
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Use `Show@grph2` to get a `Graphics3D` object:

```
Show[grph2, ViewPoint -> {0, 1, -3}]
```

[image]

**Using `Graphics3D` and `GraphicsComplex`:**

To get the line indices you can use `MapIndexed` as in @LLlAMnYP's answer. An alternative way is to use `SparseArray[adjmat]["NonzeroPositions"]`:

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pnts, Line@SparseArray[adjmat]["NonzeroPositions"]], 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 1, -3}, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> True, Boxed->False]
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your example data into the question, hope you don't mind. I think it's worth keeping open. +1 of course.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple version of what you seem to be looking for. First I enter some fake data:

```
points = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};

am = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

i.e. points (their coordinates) and adjacency matrix, respectively.

Then I want to get from the adjacency matrix to a list like `{{5,6},{3,4},{1,4}...}` which means "there is an edge between the 5th and 6th point, an edge between 3rd and 4th, 1st and 4th and so on". This could be done (and probably better done) with MMA's capabilities of working with graphs, but I'm not too fluent with those, so I just used this line of code:

```
lines = Cases[Flatten[MapIndexed[(If[# == 1, #2] &), am, {2}], 1], _List]
```

Which returns

> `{{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 5}, {3, 4},
>   {3, 6}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}}`

Finally I use `GraphicsComplex` to plot this.

```
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[points, {Line[lines]}], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

This is easily extendable to your Toyota polyhedron if you go to all the trouble of inputting the points and that 16x16 matrix.

Comment: Why didn't you use `lines = Cases[
  Flatten[MapIndexed[(If[# == 1, #2] &), adjmat, {2}], 1], _List]` and `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pnts, {Line[lines]}], Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False]`, which had matched the OP's actual data?

Comment: @Jinxed, the OP didn't include data - I copied it in from kguler's answer because I though it was worth keeping the question open and all it really lacked was example data.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It was the edit. Missed that.